# When attempting to create a Data Store for GCP's "Search & Conversaion", storage.objects.get permission is missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-iam, vertex-ai-search

For Google Cloud Platform's Search & Conversation, I am trying to create a "Data Store" using Google Cloud Storage (GCS) as the source. Step 1 is to choose the source (GCS in this case), and Step 2 is to point to the actual GCS bucket/path. After selecting the GCS bucket/path, I get the following permission error.

```
Missing required permissions: storage.objects.get
```

I have no idea which Service Account is missing the permission. However, I took a guess and thought it was the either the "compute" or "aiplatform" accounts (see the name patterns of the accounts below).

- [numbers]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Compute Engine default service account)
- service-[numbers]@gcp-sa-aiplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com (AI Platform Service Agent)

Using IAM & Admin, to these accounts, I added the following Roles.

- Storage Admin
- Storage Folder Admin
- Storage Object Admin
- Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object User
- Storage Object Viewer

However, this does not help make the permission error go away. To the actual bucket and "folder" inside the bucket, I also checked, verified and modified the permissions (eg Grant Access) for the two service accounts above. These changes also do not make the error go away.

Any ideas which service account is being used to define a Data Source for Search & Conversation. I have followed the following tutorials to no success on my own data.

- [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/before-you-begin)
- [Get started with Vertex AI Search](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/try-enterprise-search)

For the second link above, when I point to the Kaggle Movies dataset on GCS, it actually works (eg. `gs://cloud-samples-data/gen-app-builder/search/kaggle_movies`).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same steps as you did, granting `Storage Admin` role to multiple Service Accounts that could be related to Search and Conversation but nothing worked out.

However, I decided to try to change from `Fine Grained` object control access to `Uniform` access to all objects in the bucket. After changing this config of my bucket the permission error disappeared.

Feel free to try and let me know if this also worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your steps it seems working fine form me with this Roles:

[image]

But the roles was assigned to my user.

Data store creation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found adding the `storage.object.admin` permission to both my user role i.e. xxxx@gmail.com and to the compute service account: `[numbers]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I added to my user the "Storage Object Viewer" Role, and it solved the problem.

More info here: https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/access-control